# How to line up elements after they have been rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, rotation

I've got an issue lining up `div`s that have been rotated.

For example, if `.straight` has been rotated `30deg`, I want to get the new offset coordinates of the bottom right corner, so that I can set the bottom left corner of `.curve` to match up with this coordinate exactly.

In order to get the offset coordinates of the bottom right corner of `.straight`, I'm using the following:

```
var straight_width = $(".straight").width();
var br_corner_x = straight_width*Math.cos(30*Math.PI/180); //60.62
var br_corner_y = straight_width*Math.sin(30*Math.PI/180); //35
```

This is all good, but the problem is that if I set the `left` and `top` of `.curve` to these values, as follows:

```
$(".curve").css({"left": br_corner_x, "top": br_corner_y})
```

the browser rounds the pixels and positions the `left` at `61px` and leaves a tiny gap between the `div`s. For what I'm doing, this tiny discrepancy is significant.

Here is a fiddle that shows the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/39q5m71u/2/

Now, I know I can line up both `div`s in a wrapper and rotate the wrapper, and I know I can line up both `div`s and then rotate `.curve` about the the same transform-origin coordinate as `.straight`, but for reasons involving scaling the project to handle lining up multiple rotated divs with different angle values, these solutions won't work.

I'm wondering if anyone can think of an alternate approach that can line the `div`s up only ***after*** they have been rotated? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the browser is performing pixel rounding on the `left` property:

```
<div class="curve" style="left: 60.6218px;top: 35px;"></div>
```

If you manually change the value of `left` to, say, 60.49, that little gap is removed.

I was able to remove the gap by rounding `br_corner_x` down to the nearest whole number:

```
var br_corner_x = Math.floor(straight_width*Math.cos(30*Math.PI/180));
```

To deal with some of the jaggedness going on, I adding a `.container` div around the two existing divs and added:

```
.container {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/ytzw2bzf/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this eliminates the gap, it does not line the `div`s up perfectly, as now `.curve` is slightly too far left, as you can see in the screenshot. I realize there may be no better way, but I'm just wondering if there is.

Comment: I modified my answer a bit. With `backface-visibility: hidden;` it's better than before, though I'm not sure how much closer I can get.